# Importing 'body' into 'paragraphs'

Tags: migrations, paragraphs

I need to migrate an ordinary D7 multi-value long text field 'body' into D8 [paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) . As paragraphs seem to be a reference, the migration will probably be more complex than just direct field mapping. Moreover, my target paragraphs include multiple fields, not only the text body but a title as well.
Any idea or link how to accomplish this task?

Comment: You will need to create a custom plugin for the Migration API import. Then you add code like this inside [How to store values to field collection or paragraphs programmatically?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/194909/how-to-store-values-to-field-collection-or-paragraphs-programmatically/194972#194972)

Answer (score 0):

Paragraphs are entities in and of themselves - it's most straightforward to migrate the paragraphs separately, then populate the reference to the migrated paragraphs within the "parent" node migration.